# Get value from an json array if particular condition satisfy for an object in Java

Tags: java, arrays, json

```
[ {
  "revision" : "Test_10",
  "timestamp" : "2020-11-12T13:58:24.000+0000",
  "status" : "PENDING",
  "processTimestamp" : null,
  "processedBy" : null
}, {
  "revision" : "Test_9",
  "timestamp" : "2020-11-12T13:56:57.000+0000",
  "status" : "PROCESSED",
  "processTimestamp" : "2020-11-12T13:58:13.629+0000",
  "processedBy" : ""
}, {
  "revision" : "Test_8",
  "timestamp" : "2020-11-12T13:52:47.000+0000",
  "status" : "PROCESSED",
  "processTimestamp" : "2020-11-12T13:56:43.935+0000",
  "processedBy" : ""
} ]
```

This is my JSON array, I would like to get the "revision" value if the "status" value is "PENDING"

Comment: Please add your existing Java code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Comment: Use one of many available JSON parsers, iterate over objects in array, check their `status`, if it is equal to PROCESSED get its `timestamp`. If you are having problem with any of those steps use [edit] option and describe that problem in your question.